# sql aggregate on two branches without subqueries

Tags: sql

I have

```
items  ---- supporders ---- suppincoming 
=====       ==========      ============
ItemID      OrderID         OrderID
            ItemID          IncQty
            OrderQty
            SODate
```

and

```
items  ---- orderrows ---- orders
=====       =========      ======
ItemID      ItemID         OrderID
            OrderID        OrderDate
            ORQty
```

and want to sum ORQty, OrderQty and IncQty per item.

If I join all tables, the two "branches" from item produce a kind of cross-join and the amount goes up the roof.

Subqueries gives correct values, but awfully slow.

EDIT:
Please see link for MS-access runnable example.

Any better way?

regards,
/t

Comment: Can you post what your query that used sub-queries looked like?  Also, what RDBMS is this for?

Comment: POC avaliable at http://stuff.pomada.se/branches.mdb (access 2000-format). Three queries, the "sold_and_bought" hits the roof as explained.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson, please see link.

Comment: I suggest you try to optimize the subqueries version. You can post a new question with your query, your tables (as here) and the indexes you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the query can't be issued without subqueries, and obviously, MS-access with linked tables to sql-server (firebird) is a performance-pig.

Executing a parameterized pass-through query from Access solves the performance issues.

thanks
/t

Answer (score 0):

```
select itemId, count(orderQty) as OrderQty, count (incQty) as IncQty
from Items I, supporders S, suppincoming SI
where I.itemId = S.ItemId AND S.OrderId = SI.OrderId
group by I.itemID

select itemId, count(ORQty)
from items I, orderRows O
where I.itemId = o.itemId
group by itemId
```

I have not tried these queries, pardon any bugs.....I hope it works

Comment: Thanks, but I belive you misunderstand the q. I want the two sums in one go, (and not union).

Comment: in that case we just need to make one extra outer query,
select *
from (Query1) a, (Query2) b
Left Outer join on itemId

Comment: The query will first selects counts, and then we can left or right outer join, depending on which table extra rows are expected.....
however three queries will be executing....